# A question about spark distributied aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I am reading up on spark from [here](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/)

At one point the blog says:

> consider an app that wants to count the occurrences of each word in a corpus and pull the results into the driver as a map.  One approach, which can be accomplished with the aggregate action, is to compute a local map at each partition and then merge the maps at the driver. The alternative approach, which can be accomplished with aggregateByKey, is to perform the count in a fully distributed way, and then simply collectAsMap the results to the driver.

So, as I understand this, the two approaches described are:

Approach 1:

1. Create a hash map for within each executor
2. Collect key 1 from all the executors on the driver and aggregate
3. Collect key 2 from all the executors on the driver and aggregate

and so on and so forth

This is where the problem is. I do not think this approach 1 ever happens in spark unless the user was hell-bent on doing it and start using collect along with filter to get the data key by key on the driver and then writing code on the driver to merge the results

Approach 2 (I think this is what usually happens in spark unless you use groupBy wherein the combiner is not run. This is typical reduceBy mechanism):

1. Compute first level of aggregation on map side
2. Shuffle
3. Compute second level of aggregation from all the partially aggregated results from the step 1

Which leads me to believe that I am misunderstanding the approach 1 and what the author is trying to say. Can you please help me understand what the approach 1 in the quoted text is?